# Django - create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_type'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a custom user model for my django app.
Here is the code for CustomUser and CustomUserManager.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
def _create_user(self, anonymous, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, user_type, image_path):
    now = timezone.now()

    if not email:
        raise ValueError('The gives email must be set')

    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(
        anonymous=anonymous,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        email=email,
        username=username,
        home_address=home_address,
        user_type=user_type,
        image_path=image_path,
        created_time=now,
        last_login=now
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


    def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, image_path):
    return self._create_user(False, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, 0, image_path)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    anonymous = models.BooleanField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True)
    home_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(1)
    image_path = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    created_time = models.TimeField()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'home_address', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_type']

    objects = CustomUserManager()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
```

Then I get the error about unexpected argument user_type

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "manage.py", line 22, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 363, in execute_
>   from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 355, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_arg
>   v
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py
>   ", line 63, in execute
>       return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py
>   ", line 183, in handle
>       self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
>
> TypeError: create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_type'

Thank in advance if anybody can help!

Comment: Did you set this custom model as `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in the settings?

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes, I did AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'CustomUser.CustomUser'. The first CustomUser is an application

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you ever assign the custom manager to your custom model. This is indicated by the fact that it seems to be looking at the default manager in the stack trace. Try assigning your custom manager to the model [as described in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance).

Comment: Hi @MrName, I am confused, if the program is trying to use the default one, how it get the input user_type? And I have objects = CustomUserManager() in CustomUser class, so I think it should using the CustomOne

Comment: Got it, could you update the code in your original post to reflect it's current state? What is pasted there does not show `objects = CustomUserManager()`

Comment: added. Wanna hide some unnecessary method but also forget about that line, haha

Comment: It looks like your `create_superuser` function does not include `user_type` in the method signature: `def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, image_path):`

Answer (score 0):

Hi just run into the same issue, and taking a look at your code I realise an error.
The return statement of your `create_superuser()` method should be :

```
return self.create_user(False, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, 0, image_path),
```

instead of:

```
return self._create_user(False, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, 0, image_path)
```

Kindly lose the _
Hope this helps